# writing data from two JSON files into core data model with relation

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

in my application which contains a list of users with an field relating to offices i load two JSON files from a remote server. one file containing users, one file containing the offices.

my core data model contains of two entities: User and Office. they relate to each other. in user there´s a relation named office. so far so good.

but now i have to fill the fields in the entity User what works great. the list is already there. fine! but when filling the entity User with data from JSON i have to grab the appropriate managedObject from the Office entity to pass it to the User item in the User entity.

i´ve defined the office property already in the User class

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *office;
```

but what makes me headache is i have only one managedObjectContext which i´ve defined in the appDelegate. i pass the managedObjectContext to the ListViewController. see bellow:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (!context) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    // Pass the managed object context to the view controller.
    listViewController.managedObjectContextUser = context;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];  
    return YES;
}
```

but if i try to access a second managedObject for Office i´ve previously declared in the header it throws an exception:

```
- (void)updateUsers
{
    NSString *users = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kUsersFilePath]];
    if ([users length] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"usersList is == 0");
        [users release];
        return;
    }

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    usersObject = [[parser objectWithString:users error:nil] copy];
    usersList = [usersObject objectForKey:kUsersDataName];
    [parser release];

    User *user = (User *)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContextUser];
    NSError *error = nil;

    Office *office = (Office *)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Office" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContextOffice];
    NSLog(@"managedObjectContextOffice: %@", office);
```

my question is do i have to create a second managedObjectContext in my appDelegate. one for User and one for Office?

Or is there a way how i can handle fetching objects from two different entities with only one managedObjectContext in the ListViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the `managedObjectContext` refers to the whole data model, so you can do everything with your entities with that context.

After reading in a new `User` or `Office` object, try to actually **create a new object** by inserting it into the `managedObjectContext`:

```
User *user = [NSEntityDescription 
             insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" 
             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Use the automatically generated methods in your class to attach office objects to users and vice versa.

Comment: i do that already. the problem was i had two different NSEntityDescription relating both to one managedObjectContext. It didn´t work. the manageduserContext for the user was overwriten by the managedObjectContext of office. so i doubled the managedObjectContext into managedObjectContextOffice and managedObjectContextUser. Anyhow they point to the same single one managedContext in my appDelegate. strange, but now it works.